# Apache download zip archive with same url name automatically without extension

Tags: apache-http-server

I created **/var/www/mysite.local/public_html/panel.zip**

When I access **mysite.local/panel** apache serve me the ZIP file. It will not work if I put "panel/"

Why this happens and how can I prevent this?

I tested on centos, ubuntu and on a osx. All the same behaviour.

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Apr 24 2019 13:45:48

Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-04-03T13:22:37
```

My vhost conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.local
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerAlias mysite.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.local/public_html/
        CustomLog /var/www/mysite.local/access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/www/mysite.local/error.log
        RewriteMap IPblacklist txt:/var/www/mysite.local/IPblacklist.txt

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond ${IPblacklist:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} deny [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) "-" [L,F]

        <Directory /var/www/mysite.local/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: '/panel' is a file, '/panel/' is a directory. I am surprised '/panel' downloads the panel.zip file though - is there any other config going on? .htaccess etc?

Answer (score 1):

Found on another similar thread. It was the [Multiviews option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24715460).
*A MultiViews search is enabled by the MultiViews Options. If the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named foo.**